# Flutter chat app always load first when using stream builder or future builder

Tags: flutter, sockets, stream, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a question about how to create the best chat app
when ever someone open Facebook Messenger the chats is always there waiting for you there is no loading animation or indicator
Instagram is the same, the chats always there waiting for you
when I try to create a flutter chat app I think I should use stream builder and TCP connection, but it always loads when I open the screen
and using future builder and provider to notify Listeners when ever new data cam could work better ?
What do you think

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer this question because no code provided, but if you're looking for a ProgressIndicator in a FutureBuilder before messages are loaded:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: yourFutureFunction(),
    builder: (Buildcontext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return *show list of messages*
            } else {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that facebook cache the last 10 posts (for exemple ) in your phone , so when the app is initialize it bring the cached posted and it then compares if the last saved post like the recent ones in the database then it run the strem without changing nothing .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).